# Implement Scala-like Trampoline to gain tail call optimization in Rust

Tags: rust, trampoline

On the topic of tail call optimization, I found two RFCS: [271](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/271) and [1888](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1888).

Until this gets implemented, I wanted to do something inspired from Scala's `Trampoline` functionality.

The actual implementation is far from a full-fledged tail call optimization in that it replaces recursive function calls with iterative ones, but it has its use for keeping the stack depth low. My actual state of work is as follows:

```
enum Trampoline<A, R> {
    Continue(A, R),
    End(R),
}

impl<A, R> Trampoline<A, R> {
    fn start(function: &Fn(A, R) -> Trampoline<A, R>, mut arg: A, mut sum: R) -> R
    {
        loop {
            match function(arg, sum) {
                Trampoline::Continue(r_arg, r_sum) => {
                    arg = r_arg;
                    sum = r_sum;
                },
                Trampoline::End(result) => return result,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn recurse_trampolin(arg: i32, sum: i32) -> Trampoline<i32, i32> {
    if arg == 0 {
        Trampoline::End(sum)
    } else {
        Trampoline::Continue(arg - 1, sum + arg)
    }
}

fn recurse_normal(arg: i32, sum: i32) -> i32 {
    if arg == 0 {
        sum
    } else {
        recurse_normal(arg - 1, sum + arg)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", recurse_normal(5, 0));
    println!("{}", Trampoline::start(&recurse_trampolin, 5, 0));
}
```

Apart from using references for compatibility with non-`Copy` types, can this construction be further optimized or the code simplified/beautified?

Answer (score 2):

1. Run [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). It will automatically fix such things as

   - Opening curly braces go on the same line as the function signature (unless the function signature is already multiple lines).
   - There is no comma at the end of a `match` arm that uses curly braces.
2. Your function name has a typo: `recurse_trampolin`
3. Instead of taking a trait object reference (`&Fn(...) -> ...`), take a generic. This allows for better optimizations and avoids unnecessary indirection.

```
enum Trampoline<A, R> {
    Continue(A, R),
    End(R),
}

impl<A, R> Trampoline<A, R> {
    fn start<F>(function: F, mut arg: A, mut sum: R) -> R
    where
        F: Fn(A, R) -> Trampoline<A, R>,
    {
        loop {
            match function(arg, sum) {
                Trampoline::Continue(r_arg, r_sum) => {
                    arg = r_arg;
                    sum = r_sum;
                }
                Trampoline::End(result) => return result,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn recurse_trampoline(arg: i32, sum: i32) -> Trampoline<i32, i32> {
    if arg == 0 {
        Trampoline::End(sum)
    } else {
        Trampoline::Continue(arg - 1, sum + arg)
    }
}

fn recurse_normal(arg: i32, sum: i32) -> i32 {
    if arg == 0 {
        sum
    } else {
        recurse_normal(arg - 1, sum + arg)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", recurse_normal(5, 0));
    println!("{}", Trampoline::start(recurse_trampoline, 5, 0));
}
```